# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException como resolver?

Tags: c#

Olá, estou recebendo uma Exceção quando executo o código abaixo afirmando que o meu List<> está fora de faixa. Já tentei de tudo, mas sem sucesso. Como faço para resolver?

```
private List<string> conexao;

    public Conexao()
    {
        conexao = new List<string>()
        {
            [0] = "127.0.0.1",
            [1] = "5432",
            [2] = "cstdb",
            [3] = "postgres",
            [4] = "#abc123#"
        };
    }
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo Willian, está resposta te ajudaria(Em inglês) [ArgumentOutOfRangeException on initialized List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236649/10301489)

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. Muito obrigado Luiz Augusto.

Comment: O erro não está neste código, coloque onde dá o erro para podermos ajudar você

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está declarando um `List` não deve tratar como se fosse um array, informando o índice ([0], etc), a lista trabalha diferente, trate dessa forma:

```
var conexao = new List<string>()
{
    "127.0.0.1",
    "5432",
    "cstdb",
    "postgres",
    "#abc123#"
};
```

Depois se quiser pode usar o índice que vai funcionar: `conexao[0]`

Comment: Perfeito, amigo. Engraçado é que o Intelisense do Visual Studio que montou isso. Mas de qualquer forma obrigado pelas informações. Vou tentar aqui.

Comment: que bizarro, precisa demitir esse intellisense ai..:)

Comment: :) vou dar demissão por justa causa.